# IFilter replacement

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, ifilter

I'm currently using IFilters to extract text from various file (word, excel, tiff, pdf etc). I understand that IFilters have been discontinued with Windows 8. Does anyone have any recommendations on how to extract text without the native apps being installed? If it's any use I'm using C# and .Net 4

Comment: Looks like I am confusing the IFilter and the Indexing Service. I believe the newer Windows Search code uses IFilters so my code may still be ok.

Comment: Why would you vote down my answer when you say that's the solution you are going with?

Comment: I'm not using Windows Search or Microsoft Search Server - I just need the IFilter to extract text from a file so your solution to use Windows Search et al would not apply. 

It appears I was confused (and as discussed elsewhere it would appear I'm not the only one). The documentation states that the Indexing Service has gone end of life - I took this as IFilters have gone end of life too which I now believe may not be the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IFilter` is not discontinued.  Only the Windows Indexing Service is discontinued in favor of Windows Search or Microsoft Search Server.  Both continue to use IFilters.

According to [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940431.aspx), the main point of compatibility for IFilters going forward are that they support the `IPersistStream` interface.  All modern implementations should avoid requiring `IPersistStorage`, so they don't have to access the disk themselves.