# IFilter for JPG files

Tags: delphi, jpeg, ifilter

I'm using the IFilter interface to read the content of files such as .docx, .pdf, etc. For those two types (and others) this already works pretty well, but I was wondering if it is possible to use this mechanism to read the meta data of a jpg file as well.

I created a test image file and added some information to its details (Title, description, ...)

Interestingly, the Windows Indexer is able to find this file using the text that I specified as title. By using the IFilter interface, however, I retrieve only an empty string for my jpeg.

I also tested the command line tool filtdump.exe from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940434(v=vs.85).aspx#command_line, which returned the same results as my implementation.

Does anyone know how the Windows indexer is able to see the content and how I couold use the same mechanism to achieve similar results?

Comment: `IFilter` was phased out long ago. It became irrelevant after Vista was released 10 years ago.

Comment: Hello David, thank you for your answer. Could you give me a source for that information? To my knowlege, only the Windows Indexer Service is discontinued, not the IFilter interface. IFilter is still highly relevant and still used (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521301/ifilter-replacement). The test tool that I mentioned is even part of the Windows 8.1 SDK.

Comment: Since the old XP indexer has gone, expect `IFilter` support to be flaky. You ask why the modern indexer can see the content? Well, it doesn't use `IFilter`. Why don't you use the same interfaces as the modern indexer?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think that's correct. According to the official documentation of the Windows search (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc678933(v=vs.85).aspx), IFilter is still a core component for the indexing:
"Filters:  Filters are critical components in the indexing process that emit item information for the gatherer. Filters are named after the principal interface used in their implementation, the IFilter interface, [...]"

Comment: OK, fair enough. I guess you have concluded that the new Windows Search is still based on `IFilter`. I can't reconcile that with the fact that client support for `IFilter` is clearly documented as ending at Windows 7. But you seem to know more than me.

Comment: According to this article, IFilters are alive and well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940430(v=vs.85).aspx